# Vim NERDTree: show only .txt files?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Using [NERDTree plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658), I want to view only *.txt files. There is a `NERDTreeIgnore` variable, but I want something like `NERDTreeWhitelistFilter`.

Is there a way to whitelist what I see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
:let NERDTreeIgnore += ['\(\.txt\)\@<!$[[file]]']
```

Comment: What does `$[[file]]` mean, Where can I get the information about it? Thank you for your response.

Comment: @AylwynLake： please type `:help 'NERDTreeIgnore'` in you vim.

Comment: Yes, I had checked the help file. And There is no any `[file]` defined. Maybe My version 4.2.0 not contain this keyword?

Comment: @AylwynLake take a look at https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt

Comment: Thank you very much. I download it from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658 , and that version does not provide this feature. My problem solves.

Answer (score 5):

I've been playing around with this — it's an interesting problem. Maybe you could try out this regular expression for ignoring files?

Edit: talked with my co-worker. Here's the correct regular expression (my original one matched "txt" at the beginning of a file name, too).

```
^(?!.*\.txt$).*
```

Comment: I think that's the way to go. Ignore everything that does not end in *txt*, in other words.

Comment: didn't work. I typed `:let NERDTreeIgnore=^(?!.*\.txt$).*` and it gave the following error: `E15: Invalid expression: ^(?!.*\.txt$).*`

Comment: http://stevereads.com/weblog/2007/03/26/vim-and-negative-lookaheadlookbehindlookaround/ shows how to do vim lookbehinds. When focused on the NERDTree, I manually search `^\(.*\.txt$\)\@!.*` and `n` will proceed through every single line _except_ txt files -- and that's exactly what I want. _but_ ... when I type `:let NERDTreeIgnore=^\(.*\.txt$\)\@!.*` it gives me the same error as previous comment. So we're getting closer. We now have the regex in "vim-speak", but I can't seem to set NERDTreeIgnore to it (or anything else, so I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: AAaagh!! So I finally set the variable right, but it still won't work. I type `:let NERDTreeIgnore=['^\(.*\.txt$\)\@!.*']` (and I checked three times to make sure I typed it right), but after refreshing, it shows nothing. But manually searching that regex worked (see last post). I typed `:let NERDTreeIgnore=['resx']` and it properly ignored all .resx files too :(. This is way too hard.

Comment: But how to ignore anyfile except those end with '.cpp' or '.h'. I try let NERDTreeIgnore=['^(.*\.cpp\|h$)\@!.*'], it not works. I also want this regex not ignore directories.

Answer (score 0):

based on [@kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348785/kev) great answer you can also make a toggle function.

```
function NERDRefreshIfOpened()
    if g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
            :NERDTreeRefreshRoot
    endif
endfunction

function NERDTxtOnlyToggle()
    let regex='\(\.txt\)\@<!$[[file]]'
    if index(g:NERDTreeIgnore, regex) >= 0
        call filter(g:NERDTreeIgnore, {idx, val -> val != regex})
        call NERDRefreshIfOpened()
    else
        let g:NERDTreeIgnore += [regex]
        call NERDRefreshIfOpened()
    endif
endfunction
```