# NERDTree only show .cpp and .h, meanwhile not ignore directories

Tags: nerdtree

I found this question, it's very good

[Vim NERDTree: show only .txt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492587/vim-nerdtree-show-only-txt-files)

but, what also need:

```
dir1/
 -1.cpp
 -1.h
 -1.o
dir2/
dir3/
 -3.txt
```

show like

```
dir1/
 -1.cpp
 -1.h
dir2/
dir3/
```

How can I acheive this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Kev.

Use [scrooloose nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/archive/master.zip)

Instead of [Marty Grenfell nerdtree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17123)

The latter one doesn't support `[[file]]` magic flag

```
"let NERDTreeIgnore = ['^\(.*\.\(cpp\|h\)$\)\@!.*[[file]]']
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\(\.cpp\|\.h\)\@<!$[[file]]']
```

Both expresstions work.

You can type: `:help pattern.txt` and search `/@!` to see regex syntax detail.

Or there are 2 great links:

[regular-expressions look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)