# Changing NERDTree ~/.vimrc options on the fly without restarting VIM

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I would like to change my sort order dynamically. At times, I want my sources to be listed alphabetical, at times I want only one extension to be shown.

I can currently get it to work by editing NERDTreeSortOrder in my ~/.vimrc.

But how do I do this without re-launching VIM?

I tried just executing ":let NERDTreeSortOrder =  ['new sort order']"  but that doesn't really change anything. i add it to my vimrc, quit VIM and restart and it works.

By the way, if someone can tell me how to make NerdTree show *only* a specific extension, that would work for me too. I know I can make NERDTree *not show* a particular file type by adding it to ignore, but I want the other way around.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to refresh the directory (after entering `let NERDTreeSortOrder=[...]`).
While in the `NERDTree` buffer, either :

- `r` to limit the refresh to the selected directory
- `R` to refresh from the start of the root node.

---

As for whitelisting specific file extensions, have at look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492587/2650437).

Comment: Tried both. The sort order doesn't change till i quit VIM and restart. Thank you for the link to the other question, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried source-ing your `.vimrc` from within vim?

`:source $MYVIMRC` or `:source ~/.vimrc`

`:source` can be shortened to `:so`, e.g. `:so ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Works after I refresh, like the below poster's comment